# Explanation for argparse python modul behaviour: Where do the capital placeholders come from?

Tags: python, argparse

I am trying to write a command line interface (for the first time) and after reading up about `argparse`, `optparse` and `getopt` I chose `argparse` because of several recommendations here on SO and elswhere in the net. Adapting a little of the [advice of Mr. van Rossum](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=4829) I hooked up my first command line interface like this:

```
def main(argv=None):
    if argv is None:
        argv = sys.argv
    desc = u'some description'
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=desc)

    parser.add_argument('-s', '--search', help='Search for someone.')
    parser.add_argument('-c', '--do_something_else', help='Do something else.')

    args = parser.parse_args()
    print args

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

Doing `python myscript.py -h` results in:

```
usage: dblp.py [-h] [-s SEARCH] [-c DO_SOMETHING_ELSE]

some description

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -s SEARCH, --search SEARCH
                        Search for someone.
  -c DO_SOMETHING_ELSE, --do_something_else DO_SOMETHING_ELSE
                        Do something else.
```

So my first question is: **Why are `SEARCH` and `DO_SOMETHING_ELSE` written in CAPITAL LETTERS?** The second question would be: Do I break any standards? **Is there a better way (ore a nice real world example I can learn from) how to build clean and useful command line interfaces with python?** And are there **pitfalls** one should avoid, when writing cmd interfaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a couple basic argparse resources I dug up:

Some slides on argparse:
http://www.slideshare.net/tisto/argparse-python-command-line-parser

A little argparse example:
http://www.rutherfurd.net/tag/argparse/

Here is a real-world argparse example:
https://github.com/harijay/xtaltools/blob/e683fcef6a5ad7394b87382e58d4dce32a85585b/maskconvert.py

As far as avoiding pitfalls, here is a nice looking wrapper for argparse to reduce the boilerplate code you have to write for some common usecases:
http://travelingfrontiers.wordpress.com/2010/11/03/simple-python-argparse-wrapper/

Answer (score 7):

The capital letter items are just value placeholders; they're taken from the destination of the option. You can specify alternative placeholders via the `metavar=` param of `add_argument`:

http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#metavar